# iOS 7.1 Simulator weird behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, ios-simulator, size-classes

I am having project written on Swift, storyboads are using Auto-Layout and Size Classes. Everything works great on iOS 8, but when I run it on iOS 7:

iOS 7.1 iphone 5s simulator picture:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rv2cg9z014nf8r8/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20Apr%2017%2C%202015%2C%203.09.18%20PM.png?dl=0

2 main bugs: height and font. Talking about font - it is chosen as main system font.

**UPDATE:**

I created new project from scratch, set deployment target to iOS 7, turned off AutoLayout and Size Classes and still I have the same problem:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sxp5aia6ihc7nvc/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20Apr%2020%2C%202015%2C%201.00.47%20PM.png?dl=0

What do you think it can be?

Comment: While iOS7 supports much of the auto layout and size class API, it doesn't support all of it. My general advice with auto layout is that if you're not experienced with it it's best to do as much as you can programatically first to build up a better picture of what going on. Also set iOS 7 as the SDK for the app will mean you get better information on what elements aren't supported. Once you're done you could up it to 8.

Comment: I turned them off - it's not a problem connected to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are supporting iOS < 8, you need to do this:

General / App Icons and Launch Images
Launch Image Source - select LaunchImage for asset catalog.
Add a 640x1136 image for the "Retina 4" option.